# How to access more than one model class in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

Is there any way I can call more than one Model class in my jsp page.
Suppose I have two model class Student, Teacher.

And in my JSP Page I want to view some details of student as well as teacher. How can I do that?

Comment: The same way you would access a single one.

Comment: You could use ModelMap or ModelAndView.

Comment: Then how do we give a path name for the same in jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

In jsp page::

```
<% Student st=new student()%>
<% Teacher t=new Teacher ()%>
```

//this is the way how u can call the constructor of the Student class from model.